# How to interpret the value of money depending on the maturity of a bond? FM question.

Tags: solution-verification, finance, compound-interest

Consider the following exercise:

**Exercise.** A financial institution issues bonds with maturities of $13$ weeks, $26$ weeks and $52$ weeks, at zero coupon, and with a discount value $B_1(0) = 98€$, $B_2(0) = 96.5€$ and $B_3(0) = 95€$ such that all these bonds have a facial value of $100€$. Determine the continuous interest rate for the three bonds and what conclusions can you take about the value of money depending on the maturity of the bond?

**My attempt.** I was able to determine the continuous interest rate for each of the three bonds by using a continuous interest rate modulation of a zero coupon bond (instead of the usual simple interest modulation of a zero coupon bond) and obtained the following results:

$$ r_1^{\text{weekly}} = 0.155\%, \quad r_2^{\text{weekly}} = 0.137\%  \quad \text{ and } \quad r_3^{\text{weekly}} = 0.0986\%.$$

Please note that $r_i^{\text{weekly}}$ should be read as the weekly interest rate associated to the $i$-th bond.

I also computed the interest rates without considering them weekly (i.e., seeing each bond as a simple payment, disregarding the maturity time of each of them) for which I obtained $r_1 = 2\%$, $r_2 = 3.6\%$ and $r_3 = 5.1\%$. I believe that my first computation is more useful than the latter because in the second part of the exercise I am asked to compare the maturity times of the bonds.

As for the second part itself, I really don't know what I am expected to conclude. Any hints for this part are highly apreciatted.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When the question uses the phrase "continuous interest rate," that to me suggests it is asking for the **force of interest** $\delta$, not a weekly periodic rate.  As such, the force of interest of the first zero-coupon bond is given by $$\delta = \log(1+i)$$ where $i$ is the effective annual rate of interest.  Assuming $52$ weeks in a year, this would imply $$i = \left(\frac{100}{98}\right)^{4} - 1 \approx 0.0841658$$ and $\delta = \log(1+i) \approx 0.0808108$.

The forces of interest on the other bonds are computed in the same way.

In this manner, you will be able to compare the relative yields of each bond--i.e., which bond is better to purchase because the force of interest is higher.

Your second calculation doesn't help you do this comparison because the maturities are different:  if I offered you a choice between two bonds, both with face value $100$, and the first bond matures in $1$ year with a discount value of $95$, and the second matures in $10$ years with a discount value of $94$, does it make any sense to choose the $10$-year bond?  The effective interest rate over the same time period is actually much worse.  Another way to think about it is that assuming the $1$-year bond could be repurchased every year, you could earn at least $5$ per year for $10$ years, whereas you only get $6$ after $10$ years with the second bond.  That's why your second interest calculation isn't useful:  those are rates of return over the maturities of each bond.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps my tiredness got the best out of me and this might change something: the original exercise states: "Determine the the continuously compound interest rate for the three bonds". Does this change your approach? I am making this suggestion because in my class we never talked about  force of interest.

Comment: @xyz The force of interest *is* the continuously compounded interest rate.  I am surprised that you have not heard of the term before; it is one of the concepts tested in Exam FM.

Comment: When I read constinuously compounded interest rate, I think of calculating $r$ in the espression $$ B(0) = e^{-r t} F.$$ Then, I have to be careful in which units I express $t$ because this will influence the units of $r$. Is this diferent from the force of interest?

Comment: @xyz It is the same.  And yes, you will need to consider the unit of measurement for time.  In my answer, I used years, because this is by far the most common choice, but you can also calculate a weekly force of interest if you so desire.

Comment: I have computed the annual continuously compounded interest rate for each of the bonds and I obtained the following: $r_1^{\text{annual}} \approx 8.08\%, r_2^{\text{annual}} \approx 7.13\%$ and $r_3^{\text{annual}} \approx 5.13\%.$ According to your reasoning, I could now say the the first bond is the better one to invest, since it has a higher force of interest. But I don't see  how this answers the question "What conclusions can you take about the value of money depending on the maturity of the bond".  Can you be a little bit more detailed about this?